# What does "The painfully obvious with Olive Penderghast...the fake school slut" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Is there anyone can tell me in *Easy A* why Brandon says Olive should teach a course of this name? I don't get the idea of the title.

> Brandon: Are you saying that I should act straight so people will like me?
>
> Brandon: That's groundbreaking. You should teach a course at The Learning Annex. It could be called "**The Painfully Obvious with Olive Penderghast...the Fake School Slut.**"
>
> Olive: I was just suggesting that maybe these kids we call peers are onto something. You know, like Marianne Bryant. Maybe that whole stuck-up, Jesus-freak thing is an act. You know?

It's nice of you if you can explain the whole situation of the dialogue. I hope someone who has watched this movie answer it.

Comment: Is first quoted line said by Brandon? or Olive?

Comment: It's said by Brandon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon's speech (beginning with “That's groundbreaking. You should teach a course...”) is  *[sarcasm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sarcasm#Noun)*:

> A form of humor that is marked by mocking with irony, sometimes conveyed in speech with vocal over-emphasis. Insincerely saying something which is the opposite of one's intended meaning, often to emphasize how unbelievable or unlikely it sounds if taken literally, thereby illustrating the obvious nature of one's intended meaning.

That is, Brandon is making fun of Olive.  “That's groundbreaking” says her statement was important and insightful, when he means it wasn't.  “You should teach a course...” also is mocking, as is the  “The Painfully Obvious with Olive Penderghast” portion of the suggested title.  Actually, the title offers a second layer of sarcasm, because few people need to have painfully obvious things told to them, but the title is being offered as if it were positive.  Regarding the “Fake School Slut” part of the title, its relevance isn't clear to me; but if Olive were to offer a course, having that in the title would reflect negatively upon her, both for being a fake and for acting like a slut, even if not one.  So again it is a putdown by 
Brandon.